# How can line breaks be added to a data:text/plain URI?

Tags: html, line-breaks, data-uri, plaintext

My goal is to generate a text file with line breaks, using a `data` URI in HTML5's `<a download>` tag/attribute.  Currently the line breaks seem to be ignored.

Below is an example of using HTML5 attribute of `download`, where the output is an HTML file with a link. When clicked, the link can be used to open or save a file.

Example with PHP to generate such a download link:

```php
<?php
    //generate a string line with line breaks
    //i.e. using PHP:
    //where PHP_EOL is "The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for current platform"
    $content = "line" . PHP_EOL . "line"; 
?>

<a download="a.txt" href="data:text/plain;utf8,<?=$content?>">Download</a>
```

Despite the line-break in the string, currently my output is:

```
lineline
```

when expected output would be:

```
line
line
```

Examining the string using HEX, it does have the characters `0A 0D`, which represent the CR and LF, so they are indeed there before the `<a download>` tag.

Is there a way to force line breaks to be seen in the downloaded file?
If not, is this a limitation of HTML's `download` tag?

Comment: Does it work correctly without the `download` attribute (e.g., when entering the `data` URI directly in the browser)? If not, I’d guess the issue is about the `data` URI, not the `download` attribute, right?

Comment: without the `download` attribute, it still puts everything onto one line, eating the line breaks, so yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [base 64 encode it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).

The following is `"Hello\nWorld"`

```html
<a download="foo.txt"
href="data:text/plain;base64,aGVsbG8Kd29ybGQ=">
    Download
</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

In which program are you opening the file? is it notepad? That may be a problem...

Comment: Tried both Notepad and also Textpad(.com), which usually works pretty good for showing tricky linebreaks, but nope, same thing - no line breaks, using either editor.

Comment: I had same problem, when opened in notepad, but when opened in sublime text editor then it's fine

Comment: What are you doing exactly?  I downloaded Sublime, and still no linebreaks ... I am on Windows 10 Pro, using Mozilla Firefox 65.0.1.  I run the PHP as in my example, save the file, then open it using Sublime, and .. no linebreaks.

Comment: I tried every possible text editor and I got the same result as you, no line breaks. Trying to figure out why (I'm using Google Chrome).